# PollAnswerHandler does not trigger

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot

I'm developing a telegram bot that can send a survey to chat with a user, then process the user's responses.
I encountered the following problem: when the user votes in the poll (i.e. selects answer options and clicks "Vote"), the corresponding handler (send_question) is not called.
The bot sends the poll and goes to the SEND_QUESTION state.
In the tests_menu handler, a survey is created, sent to the user, and then it transitions to the SEND_QUESTION state.
What can this problem be and how can I fix it?

```
async def tests_menu(update: Update, context: ContextTypes.DEFAULT_TYPE):
    logging.info(f" Entered tests_menu handler")
    await update.callback_query.answer()
    callback_data = update.callback_query.data

    current_course = context.user_data["current_course"]

    if callback_data in [test.tag for test in current_course.tests]:
        test_tag = callback_data
        # если мы здесь, то тест с тэгом test_tag есть в данном курсе
        # и имеет статус "active" или "past". Следовательно, 
        # этот тест есть в context.bot_data["tests"]
        ind = -1
        for i in range(len(context.bot_data["tests"])):
            if context.bot_data["tests"][i]["test"].tag == test_tag:
                ind = i
                break
        assert ind >= 0
        test = context.bot_data["tests"][ind]["test"]
        student = context.user_data["current_student"]
        students = context.bot_data["tests"][ind]["students"]
        if test.status == "active":
            # active test branch
            if student not in students.keys():
                # студент зашел в тест, еще не отвечал на вопросы
                context.bot_data["tests"][ind]["students"][student] = {}
            if len(test.questions) == len(students[student].keys()):
                # на все вопросы уже ответил
                text = f"You've already answered all the questions."\
                    f"Wait until the end of the test to see your score."
                buttons = [
                    InlineKeyboardButton(
                        text=f"Back to tests",
                        callback_data=f"back_to_tests"
                    )
                ]
                keyboard = InlineKeyboardMarkup(build_menu(buttons, n_cols=1))
                await update.callback_query.edit_message_text(text=text, 
                    reply_markup=keyboard)
                return WAIT_TEST_FINISH
            else:
                # есть неотвеченные вопросы
                all_questions = test.questions
                answered_questions = list(students[student].keys())
                unanswered_questions = [question for question in all_questions\
                    if question not in answered_questions]
                question_to_ask = random.choice(unanswered_questions)
                poll = Poll(
                    id=update.effective_chat.id,
                    total_voter_count=8,
                    is_closed=False,
                    is_anonymous=True,
                    type="regular",
                    question=question_to_ask.text, 
                    options=question_to_ask.options,
                    allows_multiple_answers=True
                )
                text = f"Test: {test.title}\n"\
                f"⏳ Remaining time: TODO"
                buttons = [
                    InlineKeyboardButton(
                        text=f"Skip question",
                        callback_data=f"skip"
                    )
                ]
                keyboard = InlineKeyboardMarkup(build_menu(buttons, n_cols=1))
                await update.callback_query.edit_message_text(text=text, 
                    reply_markup=keyboard)
                await context.bot.send_poll(
                    chat_id=update.effective_chat.id, 
                    question=poll.question,
                    options=poll.options,
                    is_anonymous=True,
                    allows_multiple_answers=True,
                    protect_content=True,
                    type="regular"
                )
                return SEND_QUESTION
        # logic for the other cases
```

```
async def send_question(update: Update, context: CallbackContext):
    logging.info(f" Entered send_question handler")
    if update.poll_answer:
        print("POLL answer")
    if update.callback_query:
        await update.callback_query.answer()
        callback_data = update.callback_query.data
        if callback_data == "skip":
            pass
        return SEND_QUESTION
    
    return SEND_QUESTION
```

I do the binding of states and handlers like this: (see SEND_QUESTION state)

```
mode_conv = ConversationHandler(
        entry_points=[CommandHandler("start", start)],
        states={
            COURSES_MANAGEMENT: [CallbackQueryHandler(courses_management)],
            COURSE_MANAGEMENT: [CallbackQueryHandler(course_management)],
            TESTS_MANAGEMENT: [CallbackQueryHandler(tests_management)],
            TEST_MANAGEMENT: [CallbackQueryHandler(test_management)],
            ACTIVE_TEST_MANAGEMENT: [CallbackQueryHandler(active_test_management)],
            EDIT_FUTURE_TEST: [CallbackQueryHandler(edit_future_test)],
            ADDING_TEST: [MessageHandler(filters.Document.ALL, adding_test),
                CallbackQueryHandler(tests_management)],
            REUPLOAD_TEST: [MessageHandler(filters.Document.ALL, reupload_test),
                CallbackQueryHandler(test_management)],
            EDIT_TEST_TITLE: [MessageHandler(filters.TEXT & ~filters.COMMAND, edit_test_title),
                CallbackQueryHandler(test_management)],
            EDIT_TEST_TAG: [MessageHandler(filters.TEXT & ~filters.COMMAND, edit_test_tag),
                CallbackQueryHandler(test_management)],
            REMOVE_TEST_REQUEST: [CallbackQueryHandler(remove_test)],
            EDIT_COURSE_TAG: [MessageHandler(filters.TEXT & ~filters.COMMAND, edit_course_tag),
                CallbackQueryHandler(courses_management)],
            EDIT_COURSE_TITLE: [MessageHandler(filters.TEXT & ~filters.COMMAND, edit_course_title),
                CallbackQueryHandler(courses_management)],
            EDIT_COURSE_LINK: [MessageHandler(filters.TEXT & ~filters.COMMAND, edit_course_link),
                CallbackQueryHandler(courses_management)],
            SEND_MESSAGE_REQUEST: [MessageHandler(filters.TEXT & ~filters.COMMAND, send_message_request),
                CallbackQueryHandler(send_message_request)],
            SEND_MESSAGE: [MessageHandler(filters.TEXT & ~filters.COMMAND, send_message),
                CallbackQueryHandler(send_message)],
            ADD_COURSE_TAG: [MessageHandler(filters.TEXT & ~filters.COMMAND, add_course_tag),
                CallbackQueryHandler(add_course_tag)],
            ADD_COURSE_LINK: [MessageHandler(filters.TEXT & ~filters.COMMAND, add_course_link),
                CallbackQueryHandler(add_course_link)],
            ADD_COURSE: [MessageHandler(filters.TEXT & ~filters.COMMAND, add_course),
                CallbackQueryHandler(add_course)],
            STUDENT_MENU: [CallbackQueryHandler(student_menu)],
            JOIN_COURSE_REQUEST: [MessageHandler(filters.TEXT & ~filters.COMMAND, join_course_request),
                CallbackQueryHandler(join_course_request)],
            UNKNOWN_COURSE_TAG: [CallbackQueryHandler(unknown_course_tag)],
            ALREADY_JOINED: [CallbackQueryHandler(already_joined)],
            UNAVAILABLE_COURSE: [CallbackQueryHandler(unavailable_course)],
            JOINED_COURSE: [CallbackQueryHandler(joined_course)],
            COURSE_MENU: [CallbackQueryHandler(course_menu)],
            TESTS_MENU: [CallbackQueryHandler(tests_menu)],
            SEND_QUESTION: [PollAnswerHandler(send_question),
                [CallbackQueryHandler(send_question)],
            WAIT_TEST_FINISH: [CallbackQueryHandler(wait_test_finish)]
        },
        fallbacks=[CommandHandler("start", start)],
        per_chat=False,
        name="main_conversation",
        persistent=True
    )
```

I tried changing the per_chat parameter, but that didn't help. Removing CallbackQueryHandler(send_question) didn't help either.
I also checked that the bot is in the correct state at the moment of voting in the poll (the Skip button handler works correctly, the send_question handler is triggered).